# Trying to figure out why my program only lets me enter one item when I am trying to enter three item

Tags: python

When I run my program retail_item_list.py it will ask me to enter the first items, however, when I finish entering the data it only lets me enter one item. If anybody has any idea why it is doing this I would appreciate the help.

Here is the Retail class that I use to help interact with the main program.

```
class RetailItem:

    def __init__(self, item_description, units_in_inventory, price):

        self.__item_description = item_description
        self.__units_in_inventory = units_in_inventory
        self.__price = price

    def set_item_description(self, item_description):
        self.__item_description = item_description

    def set_units_in_inventory(self, units_in_inventory):
        self.__units_in_inventory = units_in_inventory

    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    def get_item_description(self):
        return self.__item_description

    def get_units_in_inventory(self):
        return self.__units_in_inventory

    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price
```

Here is the main program that I use to help me enter the data.

```
import retailitem

def main():

    inventory = make_list()

    print('Here is the data you entered:')
    display_list(inventory)

def make_list():

    item_list = []

    print('Enter data for three items.')
    for count in range(1, 4):
        print('Item Number ' + str(count) + ':')
        item = input('Enter the description of item: ')
        units = float(input('Enter the number of units in inventory: '))
        price = float(input('Enter the price per item: '))
        print()

        items = retailitem.RetailItem(item, units, price)

        item_list.append(items)

        return item_list

def display_list(item_list):
    for item in item_list:
        print(item.get_item_description())
        print(item.get_units_in_inventory())
        print(item.get_price())
        print()

main()
```

However this is the result I get.

```
Enter data for three items.
Item Number 1:
Enter the description of item: 
Jacket
Enter the number of units in inventory: 
12.0
Enter the price per item: 
59.95

Here is the data you entered:
Jacket
12.0
59.95
```

But I would like it to enter three items not just one.The data I am trying to enter is

### Item 1

Description: Jacket

Units in Inventory: 12

Price: 59.95

### Item 2

Description: Designer Jacket

Units in Inventory: 40

Price: 34.95

### Item 3

Description: Short

Units in Inventory: 20

Price: 24.95

Comment: You need to not return within the for loop. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def make_list():

   item_list = []

   print('Enter data for three items.')
   for count in range(1, 4):
       print('Item Number ' + str(count) + ':')
       item = input('Enter the description of item: ')
       units = float(input('Enter the number of units in inventory: '))
       price = float(input('Enter the price per item: '))
       print()

       items = retailitem.RetailItem(item, units, price)

       item_list.append(items)

   return item_list
```

The problem is the indentation of the return statement. Your program was returning the list before completing the loop

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked!